# window.location.replace() not working to redirect browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, replace, location

I make navigation with pages but this code not work, what's the problem ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 37) { // left
    window.location.replace("http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/2)";  }
  else if(event.keyCode == 39) { // right
    window.location.replace("http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/31)";  }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: None of the answers seemed to notice that the bracket in each of the URLs is inside the quotation marks, when it needs to be outside. Otherwise the use of the replace method is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't use `.replace()` for this, just assign the value directly.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnMMQ/)

```
$("body").keydown(function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode == 37) { // left
        window.location = "http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/2";
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39) { // right
        window.location = "http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/31"; 
    }

});
```

Comment: I've got to say, an answer with jsfiddle has got to be worth 10x as much as the same answer without.

Comment: Agreed...  As long as that's not sarcasm I'm sensing.

Comment: No, it's not sarcasm.  I rarely take the time to do a jsfiddle, but when I see an answer with one, I think I should get into the habit.

Comment: yeah its a great way to make an answer instantly tangible.

Comment: Any chances to know why? What's so bad about `replace()` or `assign()`?

Comment: @green - `location.assign()` is effectively the same as setting `location.href` (which is the same as setting `location` directly). Each of these adds a new entry to the browser history (back button, etc.). `location.replace()` has a very valid and different use case, it changes the page url, but does not add an entry to the browser history. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location.

Comment: you can't directly access the `window.location`  because it is read-only property

Comment: window.location.replace is working for normal URL and not working for the local file path (eg: file:///C:/1.html)

Answer (score 25):

Your code has a syntax error.  Your end parenthesis is inside the quote not outside...

Try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 37) { // left
    window.location.replace("http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/2");  }  
  else if(event.keyCode == 39) { // right
    window.location.replace("http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/31");  }
});
});
</script>
```

window.location.replace is not supported in all browsers.   Assigning the location value is always supported.   However, the reason to use replace rather than assigning the location value is you don't want the current url to appear in the history, or to show-up when using the back button. Since this is not always possible, you just need to settle for what is possible:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 37) { // left
    try { window.location.replace("http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/2"); } 
    catch(e) { window.location = "http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/2"; }
  }
  else if(event.keyCode == 39) { // right
    try { window.location.replace("http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/31"); } 
    catch(e) { window.location = "http://newsii.abudayah.com/photo/31"; }
  }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. The fallback is really useful.

Answer (score 5):

I was having trouble with this in Chrome.  I was trying to load another page from the same domain, but was using an absolute URL (e.g.`www.example.com/newurl`).  I changed it to a relative URL (`/newurl`) and it works now.

My thought is that this is a security feature to prevent the user from being redirected to a malicious site through some javascript ad.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue with it not working when reloading same page in **Chrome**. Doing the following worked:

```
   window.location.replace("/mypage1.aspx?type=abc"); //redirect to fake page
   window.location.replace("/mypage.aspx?type=abc");  //redirect to same page
```

It is a bit of a hack, but this seems to be the only thing that forces a reload on the same page in Chrome. IE and FF work without the redirect to a fake page.

Comment: IIUC this relies on first redirect not taking place immediately so second line gets to run.  But in theory, if the first happens really fast, user would get stuck on fake url and see an error page.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it's work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var url = false;
        if (e.which == 37) {  // Left arrow key code
            url = $('.prev').attr('href');
        }
        else if (e.which == 39) {  // Right arrow key code
            url = $('.next').attr('href');
        }
        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", "new url");
window.location.reload();
```