# Login issue in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I have hosted my asp.net mvc 4 application in server the application works fine in chrome,mozilla but it is not working in IE 10 and IE 11.Also when i run it in debugging mode the application works fine with IE .Here my login method contains an ajax call.
My ajax call is like this

```
$.ajax({
   url: window.contexthttproot + "/Report/ReportLocation",
   type: 'POST',
   datatype: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   cache: false,
   data: json,
   success: function (items) {
              window.location.replace("/LandingPage/Landing");
              setTimeout(function () {
              $('#spinner').fadeOut(35000);
             })
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {

            }

   });
```

Is there any issue in ajax call?

Comment: Which version of IE you use?

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898998/window-location-replace-not-working-to-redirect-browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of this:

```
datatype: "json"
```

Should be:

```
dataType: "json"
```

It's case-sensitive.

Comment: i am passing json as variable

Comment: I am passing like thisvar json = "{'location':'" + location + "','locationName':'" + loctext + "'}";

Comment: you need to change `datatype` not `data`. If that is not the case then try to run it in different version of IE to see if it happens with all IE versions or only in IE 11 and check other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think  `window.location.replace` not works with IE

Try this

```
window.location.href = '/LandingPage/Landing';
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some issues in your code, might be the reason:

```
window.location.replace("/LandingPage/Landing");
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#spinner').fadeOut(35000);
})
```

- [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)  function has two arguments, you calling it with one.
- [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) need time to be passed as argument. The delay parameter is required, but it don't give an error (or even a strict warning) without it (in firefox).

change it to:

```
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

Comment: these two functions works fine for me in chrome and mozilla.opps i didn't whats the problem with IE?