# Jquery redirect not working on live server

Tags: jquery, redirect

I intend to redirect user to a page based on the link they clicked, after logged in.Now this works perfectly in localhost. But in live server not working as expected.

WHen a user clicks on a link ,login box would pop up if they haven't logged in. SO once filled up the form, the user will be redirected to the page based on the link clicked previously. I detect the  link clicked using jQuery.

I've referred to [window.location.replace() not working to redirect browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898998/window-location-replace-not-working-to-redirect-browser).

I've tried replacing this `window.location` with `window.location.replace("https://....");`.But not working.

Now my redirect is,

```
$("a[id^=del]").on("click",function()
{

    var this_link=$(this).attr("id");
    redirect=this_link;
    alert(this_link);

    var login_status='<?php echo $_SESSION['login'];?>';
    //alert(login_status);
    if(login_status==1){
        //alert("Login");
      if(this_link=="del_avail")
      {
          window.location="https://sample.com/update_post.php";
      }
      else if(this_link=="del_create")
      {
          window.location="https://sample.com/create_post.php";
      }
    }
    else
    {
        //$('#myModal_login').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        $("#login").on("click",function()
          {

             // alert(this_link);
              $("#login_form").submit(function(){             
            var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "login2.php?id='"+this_link+"'", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {

              //alert(data);
              if(data=="'del_create'-1")
              {
                   window.location='create_post.php';
              }
              else if(data=="'del_avail'-1")
              {              
                  window.location='update_post.php';
              }
                else
                {
                    window.location='https://sample.com/login/login.php';
                }

              }
            });
            //return false;
          });

          });

    }
});
```

Comment: try window.location.href

Comment: @VikasUmrao, tried but doesn't help

Comment: @VikasUmrao, I'm seeing these errors on console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
VM1889:1 POST https://__fake__.com/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT