# JavaScript window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, replace, window, href

I am trying to figure out why the below code will work in Internet Explorer but not Chrome or Firefox:

```
 <script language='javascript'>
   window.location.replace = 'http://home.php'
 </script>
```

When I change the word 'replace' to 'href', it will work in Chrome and Firefox but no longer work in IE.

Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: Don't you mean to use the `replace()` method instead of the property?

Comment: I believe `window.location.replace` is a function.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898998/window-location-replace-not-working-to-redirect-browser

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is specific to IE.

Assign directly to `window.location` to have it portable:

```
window.location = 'http://home.php'
```