# Redirect page without page extention in javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a page, Let's say

http://www.mypage.com/pageone.html

I am redirecting it using javascript as follows

window.location.replace("http://www.facebook.com/pageone");

But to redirect the page It needs to type ".html" how can I omit ".html" extention after the http://www.mypage.com/pageone.html

To be short My expected link is:  http://www.mypage.com/pageone

Comment: You can do it with .htaccess try reading that.

Comment: If you are not using routing and just serving `.html` files, you can also make a directory named `pageone` and put an `index.html` inside the directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location.replace() not working to redirect browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898998/window-location-replace-not-working-to-redirect-browser)

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, Your trick has done the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand this small example it worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.techdefeat.com/index.html} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.techdefeat.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above example will  replace this: **http://www.techdefeat.com/index.html** with this: **http://www.techdefeat.com/index**